# How to change xml layout of second tab according to the selection of spinner item in first tab android

Tags: java, android

I have added 3 tabs as following.There is a spinner(drop down list) in “IntroductionFragment”.i want to change the layout of “RequirementFragment” programmatically according to the selection of spinner item in “IntroductionFragment”.Please help me

HomeLoanTabMainActivity.java

```
public class HomeLoanTabMainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener {
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Introduction", "Requirement", "Best offer" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_main_activity);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
}
```

TabsPagerAdapter.java

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0: 
        return new IntroductionFragment();
    case 1:     
        return new RequirementFragment();
    case 2:         
        return new BestOfferFragment();

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}

}
```

IntroductionFragment.java

```
public class IntroductionFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.introductionform_layout, container, false);
return  rootView;
```

}
  }

RequirementFragment.java

```
public class RequirementFragment extends Fragment 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.requirementFragment_layout, container, false);
return  rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: You can store the selection in a variable at Activity level and then inside onCreateView method of RequirementFragment change the layout depending upon this variable or you can try this as well http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @AtulOHolic Sir i stored the spinner selection item in a variable inside "IntroductionFragment" but how can i compare it in "RequirementFragment" as "RequirementFragment" is already constructed in "HomeLoanTabMainActivity" and onCreateView will not called once again

Comment: Ohh yes, can you please try to access it inside the onResume method. And I found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003639/android-fragment-oncreateview-called-on-tab-change

Comment: @AtulOHolic Thanks sir for your quick reply but can you please add some code in my above example code....please

Answer (score 0):

Just give this a try

Inside your RequirementFragment.java add the onResume method as below:

```
public class RequirementFragment extends Fragment 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.requirementFragment_layout, container, false);
    return  rootView;
   }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Just check if you see this every time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }

}
```

Now run your code. In case you get the Toast every time you go back and forth then we can proceed.

Comment: Sir i know Toast message will be shown but how can i change the layout of "RequirementFragment" based on stored variable from "onResume method"....

Comment: Can you explain what sort of changes needs to be done within your layout?

Comment: Also, you need to save your selection inside your HomeLoanTabMainActivity so that it is accessible inside RequirementFragment as well. Inside on resume check the value of that variable and accordingly change the layout. Let me know if this is unclear.

Comment: Actually "IntroductionFragment" contains a spinner with two items(let say "Select your memberType"=>1.Free Member 2.Paid Member) then according to the selection type the "RequirementFragment" has to show the corresponding form.Please note that in "RequirementFragment" there are two different forms which has to filled by the user...Is it makes sence?